# Modal Dialog action leading to another Modal dialog - Mobile web

Tags: mobile-web, modal-windows, overlay

Developing a mobile web page where user has to see info about a particular product via a link in the page . Let say '**See More...**' . This CTA opens up a modal dialog (lightbox/overlay... take your pick) .

User can see the detailed info and dismiss the lightbox, but there is a possibility that there might be a 'T&C' link in the content , which in turn opens another modal dialog

The new overlay completely hides the older one though.

I feel this is kind of odd and does not make any sense throwing a modal from another modal. But throughout the application we are using modal for such links , hence the predicament.

*i am considering moving the T&C action to open up in a new tab*.

**Questions :**

1. Is this method of Stacking Modal dialogs user friendly?
2. User now has to close two overlays to get back to the main app or would it be better if   the  close(X) on any modal brings him back to the application?
3. A more elegant solution if there is any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is not a good idea to include 2 levels of modal views**.

Use the modal view to bring focus on certain content temporarily. This content should have information that will let the user:

- Achieve a certain task (as in a Dialog)
- Give certain information temporarily, not too complex, that can be dismissed or closed to go back to the main view

In your scenario the modal can be used for any of the two options. It would depend on the content displayed when viewing the full post and on the importance of the T&C.

---

In answer to your questions:

1. It's not a user friendly solution, don't use two levels of modal views
2. As per the previous answer don't use two levels. If you are in need to implement both contents in modal it is probably better to **replace the modal content** than to add another level.
3. Decide which of the two contents deserves a modal view and avoid using it for the other one.

---

Some resources:

[Material design - In-context navigation](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation.html#navigation-combined-patterns)

[Material design - Dialogs](https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html#)